# What does the notation "::*" mean in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

This example was taken from a uvm_users_guide_1.1, page 27:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

 package a_pkg;
  class a;
    function void f(inout time t);
     t += 10ns;
    endfunction
  endclass
 endpackage


 program p;
   import a_pkg::*;
   ...
 endprogram
```

Is the `::` the same as `.` ?  And what does the `*` stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 26.3 *Referencing data in packages*.  The `::*` syntax is a wildcard import, defined as:

> A wildcard import allows all identifiers declared within a package to
>   be imported provided the identifier is not otherwise defined in the
>   importing scope

`::` is the package scope resolution operator.  `*` allows all identifiers to be imported, as opposed to explicitly name identifiers to be imported.

In your example, it allows access to the `a` class inside the `p` program.

Comment: Just to add one key difference between the scope resolution operator `:: `and the hierachical separator `.` is that the prefix in `name::`, the _name_ must be known to be package or class type at the point of compilation (as the source text gets parsed), versus the separator `.`, which is resolved at the end of elaboration. This means you can use `::` in many more places than you could use `.`